# Drag formulas without "dragging"

Tags: excel, vba, optimization

I have few formulas in a row and I want to drag them down. Formulas are complex and I don't have them in R1C1 format and I don't want to convert them into R1C1, but I would like to do something like:

`Range(A2:B10).Formula = Range.(A1:B1).Formula`

I know this would put the same formula into the whole range, I need a "drag effect" - so it's changes relatively to each row but **without copy-pasting**.

P.S. I don't want to copy-paste, as it eats more CPU, I'd like to have something

Comment: what about the `FillDown` method ?

Comment: @ShaiRado thanks! Do you know if it has the same CPU consumption as Copy-Paste? I need something that is faster...

Comment: never bench-marked these 2 to compare with

Comment: @ShaiRado, thanks anyway, I will use this solution if there is no other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the range that you want to fill with the formula and use `Range.FillDown`.

```
Range("A1:B10").FillDown
```

**Note:** The first Row(s) of the range must include the original formulas

Answer (score 1):

A tiny trick !:

```
Sub KopyFormulas()
    Range("A1:B1").Copy Range("A2:B10")
End Sub
```

will copy the formulas downward and **adjust** them as well !

Comment: Thank you, but sorry for not being clear. I know how to copy-paste but I don't want to use this method as it's CPU consuming.

Comment: @SergeyRyabov  Yes....I understand...sadly, it is the copy-paste that supports the adjustment activity.

Answer (score 1):

For single cells, you don't need to explicitly convert formulas to R1C1 format to use `FormulaR1C1`.

Even if you are using the standard `A1` style of referencing, you can still use

```
Range("B2:B10").FormulaR1C1 = Range("B1").FormulaR1C1
```

And this will have the effect of copying down the formula in `B1`. It doesn't change the default format -- they will still display in the `A1` format.

There does seem to be an issue with doing this with a block of two or more cells. You could do it column by column (in a loop if desired):

```
Range("A2:A10").FormulaR1C1 = Range("A1").FormulaR1C1
Range("B2:B10").FormulaR1C1 = Range("B1").FormulaR1C1
```

Whether or not this is worth the hassle (compared to the simple `.FillDown`)  is another question. You could time it.

By the way -- I wouldn't think that `.FillDown` is particularly inefficient. Did you do the usual optimizations of turning off of screen-updating, setting calculation to manual, etc.?

Comment: I have tried the method from your first answer and yes, as you have noticed, there is kind of issue with multi-column formula transfer. But I also don't understand why it doesn't work. I did the usual optimisation and `.FillDown` works just fine.

Comment: In the multicolumn approach, `FormulaR1C1` is an array rather than a simple string. Still, `Range("A2:B10").FormulaR1C1 = Range("A1:B1").FormulaR1C1` seems to extend that array in a counter-intuitive way. It doesn't simply repeat the first row 9 times, but seems to do so once before launching into some auto-fill logic which results in something probably unintended. Just why, I have no idea.